# Why there is comma after "for" word?

Tags: punctuation

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> In English, Landa then notes that his papers state that all of the
>   Jewish families around LaPadite's region have been **accounted for,**
>   except the Dreyfuses, who have vanished completely in the past year.

I never saw **comma** after "**for**".

Does this make sentence correct?

Answer (score 3):

*Accounted for* is itself a **phrasal verb**.

From Dictionary.com:

> 12.
>   to give an explanation (usually followed by for):
>   to account for the accident.
>
> 13.
>   to answer concerning one's conduct, duties, etc. (usually followed by for):
>   to account for the missing typewriters.
>
> 15.
>   to cause (usually followed by for):
>   The humidity accounts for our discomfort. His reckless driving accounted for the accident.

**Now, to answer your question:**

Phrasal verbs **can have pauses after them like any other verb**, in disregard to the use of the prepositions contained in the verbs.

> The president had the elections called off.
>
> Everything has been cut off, so you must make do with what you have.
>
> That's the key I was looking for!
>
> There are no jobs at XYZ that you can currently apply for, due to internal turmoil at the company.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, except that "Phrasal verbs can thrown before pauses like any other verb" both has a grammar error ("Phrasal verbs can __be__ thrown before...") and is really a weird way of looking at the use of verbs.  The pause doesn't pre-exist the use of the verb; you don't position the verb in relationship to the pause, but the pause in relationship to the verb.  So I changed the phrasing entirely.

Comment: @Codeswitcher Thanks, I always appreciate people just going ahead and fixing my stuff as 1. I rush many of my answers to go do something else IRL, and that 2. I don't have anywhere near the expertise and instructional  language mastery as people with over 10k rep and other experts.

Answer (score 2):

The comma demarks the end of the main sentence

> Landa then notes that his papers state that all of the Jewish families around LaPadite's region have been accounted for.

which happens to end with the preposition "for", as in

> All present and accounted for, sir!

Answer (score 1):

> In English, Landa then notes that his papers state that all of the Jewish families around LaPadite's region have been accounted for, **except the Dreyfuses, who have vanished completely in the past year.**

The comma is very well placed here. The part in the bold is the extra information provided, which can be removed without affecting the meaning of the main sentence, like this:

> In English, Landa then notes that his papers state that all of the Jewish families around LaPadite's region have been accounted for.

The information is extra because the vanishing of the Dreyfuses family is a known fact. Everyone knows that the family either died or vanished.